# Message filter indicated that the application is busy

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, excel-interop

I've looked through a lot of the other threads on this but none of those solutions has helped me.  I'm trying to open Excel via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to load data into a worksheet.  I have tried this [solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but that did not solve my issue.  I have also seen others say that settings DispayAlerts to False helped them, however that did not resolve my issue.  I even tried adding in a 5 second wait to give Excel time to fully open but still no luck.  A small sample of my code that I'm using to open Excel is below.  This is working without issues on two machines that I've installed my application on, but the third on (2012 R2 64-bit server running Excel 2010 32-bit) is causing me all kinds of headaches.  Unfortunately, because I can't replicate this on my testing machine with Visual Studio installed, I can't debug the error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim _excel As New Excel.Application
Dim WBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing

_excel.DisplayAlerts = False
WBook = _excel.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(FolderPath, FileName))
```

Comment: Presumably you are getting the an Application Busy error when the code attempts to open the file.  Is this correct?  Have you added code to determine how the application object was obtained when the error occurred (you have 2 paths shown)?  If it is GetActiveObject, then that instance could be in a busy state waiting for user interaction.

Comment: You bring up a good point.  I realized after I read your comment that I don't need check if an instance of Excel was already running.  I've updated my post to accommodate for this update.  It's looking like the issue is occurring on the _excel.Workbooks.Open command because I can see the Excel process opening in the Task Manager.

Comment: I just did some more testing and I'm able to create a new Excel file without issue.  I only get this error when I'm opening an existing Excel file, which makes me think that my code is trying to progress before the Excel file is fully loaded.  Is there anyway to force my code to wait until Excel is fully loaded and the Workbook has fully opened before continuing?

Comment: Google "excel imessagefilter", take the first hit.  Shows you how to replace the message filter so you can tell Excel to simply continue waiting until it is no longer busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved. Creating an OleMessageFilter with this [link](http://support.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com/training/se/107/api/OleMessageFilterUsage.html) and converting my BackgroundWorker to an STA Thread with help from this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You) seemed to do the trick.  Had to pretty much rewrite my entire background process but at least it's working.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: So what was causing the error? Could you please update the link about `OleMessageFilter`, for it no longer works?

Comment: Excel was trying to process things while my code was still running which was throwing the error.  I had to add the OleMessageFilter to determine what Excel was doing and allow my code to handle it appropriately.

Seeing as this is nearly a year old I don't recall what page the first link was supposed to go to.  I have updated it with a similar link.  For future reference, a quick google of OleMessageFilter got the link that I'm now using.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link, Shaun. Observer that any link can be made permanent by dint of the [Internet Time Machine](https://archive.org/web/).

Comment: Can you please calrify this: did *OleMessageFilter* help you only to diagnose the problem, whereas to fix it you had to modify your other code? I am asking all this becase I am having the same problem now...

Comment: The OleMessageFilter was telling solution. I was originally using g the BackgroundWorker class but had to ditch that because in order to use the OleMessageFilter properly you need to set your background thread to STA. So I had to manually create a "background worker" using the second link in my answer.

Comment: Using *OleMessageFilter* in STA thread has solved my problem as well. I also tried repeating the invocation with a delay in a loop, as the RETRY_LATER constant seems to suggest, but it didn't help somewhy...