# Winforms project opening Excel file inconsistently

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

I have a stock exchange simulator that app that, on open, opens and reads the contents of an excel workbook into a list, the workbook contains all the stock information as stock data types.
Currently the program sometimes fails to open a project, showing an 'call was rejected by callee' error.

Does anyone know what changes I should make to my code so the app can open and communicate with the excel file consistently?

```
    Public Sub LoadStocksToList()
        'open stocks file and instantiate new stock objects with values from the excel database

        'initialise variables 
        Dim ticker As String = ""
        Dim name As String = ""
        Dim val As Double = 0
        Dim vol As Long = 0
        Dim mktcap As Double = 0
        Dim owned As Long = 0


        If IsFileLocked(file) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Excel file is currently locked by another process")
            Application.Exit()
        End If

        Dim xl As New Excel.Application

        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

        Try

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to database...")

            xl.DisplayAlerts = False
            xl.ScreenUpdating = False

            wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file, [ReadOnly]:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
            ws = DirectCast(wb.Worksheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
            wb.RefreshAll()


            Dim totalRow As Integer = xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'total number of rows

            For i = 1 To totalRow
                With xl.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    ticker = .Range(("B" + i.ToString)).value  'assign value from cell in each row to variable
                    name = .Range(("C" + i.ToString)).value
                    val = .Range(("D" + i.ToString)).value
                    vol = .Range(("E" + i.ToString)).value
                    mktcap = .Range(("I" + i.ToString)).value
                    owned = False
                End With
                name = FormatStockName(name) 'format the stock name to exclude uneeded characters

                Dim Values As New List(Of Double) 'list of price values for that stock item
                Values.Add(val) 'add the first stock price to the list of vlaues 
                Dim Times As New List(Of DateTime) 'list of times of price change
                Times.Add(DateTime.Now) 'add first tm=ime to list of times
                'create new object and add to list of objects
                StocksList.Add(New Stock(ticker, name, vol, mktcap, Values, Times, owned))
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Database cannot currently be accessed. Please try again later" & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Application.Exit()

        Finally

            xl.DisplayAlerts = True
            xl.ScreenUpdating = True

            If ws IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws)
            If ws IsNot Nothing Then
                wb.Close(False)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb)
            End If
            If xl IsNot Nothing Then
                xl.Quit()
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl)
            End If

        End Try
```

I have tried creating a new file, changing the autosave settings in excel, and adding code blocks to check if the file is busy before trying to open it

Comment: The question does not do a good job at describing the error message.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006279/message-filter-indicated-that-the-application-is-busy) for a possible match.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks I've tried to amend this, the error just says 'call was rejected by calle'

Comment: Then I linked the correct Q+A.  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514548/how-to-solve-exceptioncall-was-rejected-by-callee-exception-from-hresult-0x8).